# Echo file URL from Laravel storage

Tags: php, laravel-5

Im using this code in my laravel view to echo a files path, but its coming up in chrome dev tools with a 404 response.

`<img src="{{ URL::to('/').Storage::url($post->image) }}">`

which echos this onto the page

`http://localhost:8000/storage/public/bd0e2f7f.png`

The file lives there and this is the correct name for the file so im not entirely sure why its coming up with a 404!

Comment: check httpd's error log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like even though it sees like your path is fine from the `app` root folder it's not where laravel is looking for it. Laravel will look inside `app/public` for your path, resulting in an internal `app/public/storage/public/bd0e2f7f.png` which, unless you've created a symbolic link between the `app/storage/public` and `app/public, wont find the file.

The solution, [taken from the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/structure), is to run:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

from the command line which creates the above-mentioned link, and will allow you to access the file with the url `http://localhost:8000/storage/bd0e2f7f.png`, not `http://localhost:8000/storage/public/bd0e2f7f.png`

#### From the docs

> *The `storage/app/public` directory may be used to store user-generated files, such as profile avatars, that should be publicly accessible. You should create a symbolic link at  public/storage which points to this directory. You may create the link using the  php artisan storage:link command.*
> <sup>[source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/structure)</sup>

Comment: Right thanks i have the docs open but completely overlooked that ill do what it sais and let you know thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this! i completely overlooked that section on the site but it ended up solving the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution can be:

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url($post->image) }}">
```

Reference [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#file-urls) .

I am assuming you have included `Storage` as you also used it in your code, if not then use this:

```
<img src="{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::url($post->image) }}">
```

Comment: You dont need to include the whole path of storage for it to work `{{ Storage::url($post->image) }` <-- that works, but it still returned a 404, i needed to create a symbolic link for laravel to successfully look in the storage folder